# mysql query - select bottom n records

Tags: mysql

i have field ID with records:

```
1
2
3
.
.
9
10
```

is there mysql query syntax like `select bottom 5 * from table order by id desc`?

```
8
7
6
5
4
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

please try running following query.

```
select column_name from table_name order by id desc limit 5;
```

Comment: hello Lucifer, thanks for your answer.. i have 1 more question, what if i want the result like: `8 7 6 5 4` ?

Comment: ok for that answer you mean you want 5 records starting from top 3rd position right ? I can write query for it

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT id FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5
```

see [LIMIT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/select.html)

If you like to select entries 10,9,[8,7,6,5,4],.. try (3 start index, 5 row count)

```
SELECT id FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3,5
```

Or 1,2,3,[4,5,6,7,8],9,10

```
SELECT id FROM table ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 4,5
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `LIMIT` keyword in mySQL

Examples:

```
 SELECT * FROM `your_table` LIMIT 0, 10
```

This will display the first 10 results from the database.

```
SELECT * FROM `your_table` LIMIT 5, 5
```

This will show records 6, 7, 8, 9, and 10

```
SELECT * FROM `your_table` ORDER BY 1 DESC LIMIT 5, 5
```

This will show records 10, 9, 8, 7 , and 6

[SOURCE](http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/Limit_sql.htm)